# Creating a viewmodel on an existing project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a viewmodel to a project because I want my view to use two separate models. I've looked at different tutorials trying to learn how to do this but I am having some trouble. Before, the view was strongly binded(typed?) to the Person model, but now when we add a person, we want them to upload a file, but this file is in its own table in the database so I had to create a new FileToBeUploaded model

I created a new class and added the properties I wanted to it

```
namespace Project.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModel
    {

        public Person personVM { get; private set; }
        public FileToBeUploaded fileVM { get; private set; }


     }
}
```

Now my problem is when I want to strongly bind this to the view I am using, I write

```
@model Project.ViewModel
```

instead of the old Project.Models.Person

But I get an error saying "Project.ViewModel is a namespace but is used like a type"

So I don't know if I'm missing some steps in between creating the viewmodel and trying to access it in the view, and I feel like the tutorials I've seen on it are not very clear about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a namespace, your full type name is `Project.ViewModel.ViewModel` (namespace is `Project.ViewModel` and class name is `ViewModel`) so use this using instead:

```
@model Project.ViewModel.ViewModel
```

Comment: Wow, that was oddly simple. Once I do that, is it as simple as replacing any instances of model => model.Personproperty with model => model.personVM.Personproperty ?  [in the view]

Comment: okay, I guess my final question now is...how can I access the ViewModel in the controller? Should I use a using statement at the top?

Comment: you can add `using Project.ViewModel;` at the top of the file or initialize your model using full qualifier, e.g. `var viewModel = new Project.ViewModel.ViewModel();`

Comment: I wasn't sure whether to ask this here or not, but it turns out that the FileToBeUploaded model was a property of the Person model (and there is a 1 to 1 relationship between the two tables), so it turns out that the FileToBeUploaded is already available in my view. In this situation, does it make sense to even make a separate ViewModel? (I got like a million errors trying to use one, and I just kinda backed away from it)